# How to add a compiled module to qbs

Tags: qt, qmake, qbs

1. There is a Linux machine on which cross-compilation for Raspberry Pi is configured.
2. At some point it was necessary to add the Qt.charts module
3. The module is compiled and the project using qmake sees it perfectly and everything works as expected.
4. However, the qbs project gives an error message

> Dependency 'Qt.charts' not found for product 'cu-tempmeasurer'.

How to solve this problem?

Code from qbs file:

```
Depends {
  name: "Qt";
  submodules: [
    "core",
    "gui",
    "network",
    "serialport",
    "widgets",
    "printsupport",
    "charts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The modules are looked up in mkspecs//modules/ under the qt base dir. There should be a qt_lib_charts.pri file there along all the similarly named files for the other modules. If it isn't, then QtCharts is not properly installed.
Also make sure that qbs picks up the right Qt installation, in case you have several on your system.

Comment: mkspecs//modules/qt_lib_charts.pri  is present. How to check that the QBScorrectly selects Qt

Comment: It shows which qmake it picks when resolving. Use --force-probes-execution to turn off the caching and force re-setup of Qt modules.